# How to make box out of asterisks in java? nested loops?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, if-statement, nested-loops

Hey I really need help with a program for my java programming class. I'll put  in  the instructions and the code I have thus far. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!!
Instructions:
Write a program called Box (Box.java) that will print/displays a hollow box shape 
using asterisks (*). The program will read in an even number in the range 2 to 24 to 
specify the number of rows/columns in the box. Display an error and re-prompt for 
the number if an incorrect value was entered. The program will then display a hollow
of the appropriate size. Hint: Use loops within loops. 
basically it should make a square box, so if you give it the number boxSize = 5 the output is a box with dimensions 5x5. the outline is made of asterisks but the inside is empty

heres what I have code wise so far

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Box
{

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        //numrows and numcols are equal however the spacing is differnt
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter an even number (2-24):  ");
            int boxSize = input.nextInt();

        int numRows = boxSize;
        int numCols = numRows;
        // This program demonstrates compound decisions with the logical and operator &&
        //asks if the number is less than or equal to 24 and greater than or equal to 2 and that the remainder is 0 
        //when divided by 2, checks if its an even number like it should be

        if(boxSize >= 2 && boxSize <= 24 && boxSize%2 == 0)
        {   
            //nested loops are used to print out the asterisk in the correct pattern
            for(int r = 0; r<numRows; r++)
            {
                    System.out.println("*");
                for(int c = 0; c<numCols; c++)      
                {   
                            System.out.print("*");    
                }
                    }
        }
    }

            //This program demonstrates compound decisions with the logical or ( || ) operator
        //checks if any of the following are true
        //if one or more is true then that means that it is an incorrect number
        //then reprompts the user to put in a new number then checks again
        if(boxSize<2||boxSize>24||boxSize% 2 != 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Value must be an even number from 2-24");
        }
```

Basically my problem is I don't know what to put in the loops and where to get the shape. I also don't know how to make it REPROMPT for a boxSize value again if the number is odd or not between 2 and 24 and it also needs to display the error message that value must be between 2 ans 24, and even ect.

Comment: Could you add in the missing braces? I just removed some whitespace from your post and noticed they weren't lining up.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach with nested loops is basically fine. Just the stuff inside is not quite what you are looking for.... What you want is more like this:

```
for(int r = 0; r<numRows; r++) {
    for(int c = 0; c<numCols; c++) {
        // print a "*" ONLY IF on border, and " " otherwise 
    }
    // here you finished printing the "*"/" ", so print just a newline
}
```

for promting and reprompting I would use a `do {} while(yourIfCondition)` loop, to reshow the prompt.

Comment: can you elaborate on how I might check if its on the border to print the *? Also, after the inner loop you said "here you finished printing the "*"/" "" so does that mean just print an empty line like System.out.println();?

Comment: Also forgot to ask when you reprompt the user I know what should go in the do part (error message and ask for scanner input again) but I have 2 questions: 1. can I still call the int boxSize like I did earlier? 2. what kind of condition should I use? Because I have no idea how many times someone might but in incorrect data. What would you recommend?    Anyway, thanks for your help, I appreciate it!

Comment: spoke too soon I put this for the do while and it just keeps reprompting even if I give it acceptable data

Comment: do
  {
   System.out.println("Value must be an even number from 2-24");
   System.out.print("Enter an even number (2-24):  ");
               int boxDimension = input.nextInt();

  }while(boxSize<2||boxSize>24||boxSize% 2 != 0);

Answer (score 0):

Here. I put all of it in one method. Notice there's so many ifs. You can optimize by using the ternary operator if you have reached that part in your course.

```
public static void main(String...args){
        int boxSize = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            System.out.print("Enter box size [-1 to quit] >> ");
            boxSize = input.nextInt();

            if(boxSize == -1){
                System.exit(0);
            }

            /* check if number is valid */
            if(boxSize < 2 || boxSize > 24 || boxSize % 2 != 0){
                System.err.println("--Error: please enter a valid number");
                continue; // prompt again
            }

            // draw the box
            for (int col = 0; col < boxSize; col++) {
                for (int row = 0; row < boxSize; row++) {
                    /* First or last row ? */
                    if (row == 0 || row == boxSize - 1) {
                        System.out.print("*");
                        if (row == boxSize - 1) {
                            System.out.println(); // border reached start a new line
                        }
                    } else { /* Last or first column ? */
                        if (col == boxSize - 1 || col == 0) {
                            System.out.print("*");
                            if (row == boxSize - 1) {
                                System.out.println();
                            }
                        } else {
                            System.out.print(" ");
                            if (row == boxSize - 1) {
                                System.out.println();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }while (true);
    }
```

Comment: I misspelled height. But oh well

Comment: that helps and I definitely would have done that approach myself, however the class I'm in is beginners java(credits didn't transfer so I'm in a way too easy class) and they wont let me use OOP, everything has to be in the main method

Comment: what are System.err and System.exit? Also what does line continue; do? Thanks!

Comment: System.err is identical to System.out only that System.err is for printing errors. System.exit closes your application. Continue goes back to continue with the loop without executing any code after it (continue).